# Using cell renderer on group cell

Tags: javascript, typescript, ag-grid

Disclaimer: I'm using [master/detail](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-master-detail/)

I have an image column as my first column in my grid which I've written a cell renderer component for. I have `checkboxSelection = true` and also wanted to use this column to expand and contract the detail groups.

I've tried doing (in columnDefs):

```
      cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer',
      cellRendererParams: {
        innerRendererFramework: AgGridImageFormatter
      },
```

and (after registering `imageFormatter` as `AgGridImageFormatter`)

```
      cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer',
      cellRendererParams: {
        innerRenderer: 'imageFormatter'
      },
```

Note that `AgGridImageFormatter` on its own works fine, and `agGroupCellRenderer` on its own works fine. It's when trying to use the two together that the cell doesn't render at all (except for the checkbox). No group arrows, nothing.

Comment: You have to show that image once the row is expanded or you have to show image in row ?